# Not able to set Redaction Color in iText7 (C#)

Tags: itext7

I'm not able to change PDF redaction's color in iText7 + PDFSweep using the C# code below.  The RED redaction box takes effect only on the first page of the PDF file, then on subsequent pages the color of the redaction box reverts back to BLACK

```
String input = SRC_FOLDER + "/report.pdf";
String output = SRC_FOLDER + "/report_redacted.pdf";

CompositeCleanupStrategy strategy = new CompositeCleanupStrategy();
strategy.Add(new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(@"(\d\d\d\d)").SetRedactionColor(ColorConstants.RED));

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(input), new PdfWriter(output));
PdfAutoSweep autoSweep = new PdfAutoSweep(strategy);
autoSweep.CleanUp(pdf);
pdf.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in pdfSweep.

`ìText` handles documents on a page by page basis.
In order to be able to re-use the same strategy on different pages, every `ICleanupStrategy` needs to provide a `reset` method.

The current implementation for that `reset` method for `RegexBasedCleanupStragegy` is

```
public ICleanupStrategy reset() {
    return new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(this.pattern);
}
```

Which copies the strategy's pattern, but not its color. As a result, on every page but the first one, the color will default back to black.

To fix this, simply create your own implementation that overrides this behavior to also copy the color.

I will report this as a bug (iText developer here)

for the sake of completion, this would be the fixed approach:
public class RegexBasedCleanupStrategy extends

```
RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy implements ICleanupStrategy {

private Pattern pattern;
private Color redactionColor = ColorConstants.BLACK;

public RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(String regex) {
    super(regex);
    this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
}

public RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(Pattern pattern) {
    super(pattern);
    this.pattern = pattern;
}

@Override
public Color getRedactionColor(IPdfTextLocation location) {
    return redactionColor;
}

public RegexBasedCleanupStrategy setRedactionColor(Color color) {
    this.redactionColor = color;
    return this;
}

public ICleanupStrategy reset() {
    RegexBasedCleanupStrategy copy = new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(pattern);
    copy.redactionColor = redactionColor;
    return copy;
}
}
```

Comment: This is currently fixed in a branch. We are waiting for the build to start, and the tests to pass. Then it can be merged into develop. Once develop has been built, a snapshot will be made automatically.